# shim-signed disable secure boot

Tags: lubuntu

Can someone help me please.I went to install a GBA emulator, mednafen, and it wants me to disable secure boot (I am running lubuntu on ubuntu 16.04 LTS). is there anyway to skip this or if I have to disable it, would it harm my computer in anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling secure boot for Linux these days is usually required when loading unsigned kernel modules, e.g. some proprietary graphics drivers.

With secure boot active, this is not possible, so if you need these you have to disable it.

*When deciding to do so, carefully consider if you trust the source of the module.*

There will probably be different opinions on this, personally I think it is a good idea to have it enabled, but this is not always practical (on my gaming computer, it is disabled).

In general I'd say just use the same judgement as you would when downloading a random .deb package from the internet and you should be fine.

Comment: so if i disable it, would it affect my computer itself in anyway, since i will be eventually be installing windows 7 on this machine.

Comment: No, disabling it will not do anything besides telling the firmware that unsigned code is ok to load during boot. The linux kernel, when booted this way, will also not load unsigned modules. You can always turn it back on later.